# How can I get same <a> tag result in document.write() script?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a list using script. but the result is not same.
Could you tell me, How can I fix this?

```
 <ul>
        <li><a href="Web Development.html">Web Development</a></li>
        <li><a href="Automotive Design.html">Automorive Design</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Editorial Design.html">Editorial Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="3D Modeling.html">3D Modeling</a></li>
        <li><a href="Fine Art.html">Fine Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Help.html">Help</a></li>

</ul>

    <ul>
        <script>

            var page_list= document.querySelectorAll('a');
            
            var i = 0;

        while(i<page_list.length){
        document.write('<li>'+page_list[i]+'</li>');
        i=i+1;
        }
        document.write(page_list[1]);
        </script>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your program does produce a list of URLs

Click the blue button to see it work.

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Web Development.html">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="Automotive Design.html">Automorive Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="Editorial Design.html">Editorial Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="3D Modeling.html">3D Modeling</a></li>
  <li><a href="Fine Art.html">Fine Art</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Help.html">Help</a></li>

</ul>

<ul>
  <script>
    var page_list = document.querySelectorAll('a');


    // This will append to the web page, the URLs of each link, each formatted as a bullet point, i.e. list item.
    var i = 0;
    while (i < page_list.length) {
      document.write('<li>' + page_list[i] + '</li>');
      i = i + 1;
    }
    
   
  </script>
</ul>
```

## Did you want the items you produce with `document.write` to be the link text, rather than the URLs?

If so, try this:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Web Development.html">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="Automotive Design.html">Automorive Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="Editorial Design.html">Editorial Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="3D Modeling.html">3D Modeling</a></li>
  <li><a href="Fine Art.html">Fine Art</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Help.html">Help</a></li>

</ul>

<ul>
  <script>
    var page_list = document.querySelectorAll('a');

    // This will append to the web page, the Link Text of each link, each formatted as a bullet point, i.e. list item.
    var i = 0;
    while (i < page_list.length) {
      document.write('<li>' + page_list[i].innerText + '</li>');
      i = i + 1;
    }
    
    // This will append the 2nd URL (#1, with the first being #0), without formatting as a bullet point.
    document.write(page_list[1]);
  </script>
</ul>
```

## Or did you want to reproduce a complete link?

i.e. displayed on screen as the innerText, but functioning as a link (containing the full URL inside it)?

If so, try this:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="Web Development.html">Web Development</a></li>
  <li><a href="Automotive Design.html">Automorive Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="Editorial Design.html">Editorial Design</a></li>
  <li><a href="3D Modeling.html">3D Modeling</a></li>
  <li><a href="Fine Art.html">Fine Art</a></li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="Help.html">Help</a></li>

</ul>


<script>
  var page_list = document.querySelectorAll('a');

  document.write('<ul>')
  var i = 0;
  while (i < page_list.length) {
    document.write('<li><a href=' + page_list[i] + '>' + page_list[i].innerText + '</a></li>');
    i = i + 1;
  }
  document.write('/<ul>')
</script>
```

## One more thing - the `UL` markers

I see you are trying to stuff the entire `script` tag inside a `ul` tag, in the hope that this will make the output go into a UL list. Nice try! But it won't work. 8-)

Wherever you write the document.write, it will always be APPENDING to the web page, i.e. at the end. So to get the effect you want you should put a document.write of the `UL` tag before you do your list of document.writes, and a `/UL>` afterwards obviously.

Best to mentally think of `document.write` as really being named `document.append`.

Comment: Thank you mate! it appends like 'https://stacksnippets.net/Web%20Development.html' now. I would check on the server I guess it will work.

Comment: but...! it doesn't. how can I make a list exactly same using script?

Comment: oh you already edited :) how kind. thank you so much!!

Comment: OK *now* I understand what you are wanting. You really do want to reproduce the HTML appearance, purely with document.write.   To do that you need to insert BOTH the "text" part AND the "url" part, into an `<A>`...`</A>` item.  Please mark as correct if it is working 8-)

Comment: It produces text of links but I want the function as well. :’ Thank you for your help mate.

Comment: oh it works!!!!! how fast are you!!! Thank you so much! and where is 'mark as correct'? sorry I'm first day in here.

Comment: Incidentally you have one more misunderstnanding that i will add to the answer

Comment: I did I did :) thank you so much have a great day!

Comment: Misunderstanding? Which one?

Comment: Just your funny plan to stick a program inside a tag, in the hope that the output of the program will go there. I don't blame you. I had lots of experience of programming before I came to HTML/JS, and its a whole new mindset, so it took me a while to work out what the hell is going on. 8-)

Document.write should originally have been entitled document.append, to avoid this, hehehe

Comment: Ahhhhh I barely understand what you said. You can blame me there is no damage because I still have beginner's buff LOL. Anyways, Thank you sooooo much bro:)

Comment: You wrote: 
UL
   SCRIPT
       blah blah blah
   /SCRIPT
/UL

And you were hoping the SCRIPT would add list items within UL tags. But it doesn't. The output of the document.writes goes at the END of the web page, regardless of where you type the actual document.write statement. So instead you have to document.write the UL tag, then the individual items as LI tags, and then the /UL tag. In the 3rd code block I gave you I have done that. Compare the "UL" in my 3rd code block, to that in your initial question.